# Series with "dark" hero riding futuristic bike

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I have very few details about it but here I go:

- I watched a few episodes on French television (Canal+ I think) during late 90s/early 2000s but it was definitely not a French series
- It was about some sort of vigilante
- It took place in some future dystopia
- Most of the scenes took actions during the night (or in a dark environment)
- The hero was a white male who wore a special suit and had a futuristic bike
- The suit and the bike were in a secret hideout, it felt really Batman-inspired

Alas, I don't remember anything about the plot, but if you have questions I will try to answer them.

Comment: Holy crap. This is something that has been bothering me for _years_ but I could barely remember anything about it. I vaguely remembered seeing something with a robot ninja and a motorcycle when I was about 4 years old but assumed that since that was literally all I remembered I would never find out the answer, yet here we are.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This could be [***Super Force***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098917/) (1990)...

> The series is about a former astronaut who uses an advanced combat suit and motorcycle to fight crime in the city of Metroplex during the year 2020. Among the features of the suit were enhanced strength and armament, whereas the motorcycle had an array of James Bond-type gadgets and weapons.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Force)</sup>

Special Suit

[image]

Special BIke

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much, I had been looking after it for years! :D

Comment: Before reading this answer I was sure it was Street Hawk (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_Hawk), the motorbike version of Knight Rider

Comment: @PabloLozano Street Hawk was my first "go to" but it didn't quite fit. I used to *love* Street Hawk. Fortunately a quick Google gave me other options. :)

Comment: Don't forget, the suit was powered by the Millennium Cell......explicitly mentioned bearing no semblance to another copy written Millennium Cell battery of the era. If you find and watch it, you are in for some interesting era TV....female alien bounty hunters and all!